# Need some help sorting an array of structures in c#

Tags: c#, sorting, struct

Hello I would Like to receive some help. I have this structure:

```
 struct data
    {
        public String names;
        public int number;

    }
```

I've been asked to show this structure in the console  sorted alphabetically (by evaluating the names)  I don't really know how to do this, I know how to sort arrays but i don't know how to sort a structure like this.

I am a beginner, any help is received thanks.

Comment: Show how you sort your array. The only thing you need to do is to change array subscript to array subscript + property in your sorting condition.

Comment: nested for loop checking data[i].names with the temp variable or whatever you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might do the trick for you

```
data[] datas = new[] { 
     new data() { names = "Mohit", number = 3 },
     //More data like that
}
```

and then

```
Array.Sort<data>(datas, (x,y) => x.names.CompareTo(y.names));
//or
Array.Sort(datas, (x,y) => string.Compare(x.names, y.names));
```

Or by using System.Linq

```
datas.OrderBy(x=>x.names);
```

Comment: Felt happy to help you.